# Webpack for shopify scss.liquid

Tags: webpack, shopify, liquid

Are there any loaders that can compile the scss.liquid files into css files for webpack? If there isn't, are there any other alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

[Sass loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) does not arrange?

U can use it by next rule:

```
{
  test: /\.scss\.liquid$/,
  loader: 'raw-loader'
}
```